# The security of DDH with multiple instances?

Tags: security-definition, hardness-assumptions

Let $G$ be a finite group of prime order $p$, and $g$ a generator of $G$.
The standard DDH is hard to distinguish two distributions
$$ 
\{ (g, g^a, g^b, g^{ab}) : a, b \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_p\} \text{ and } \{ (g, g^a,g^{b}, g^r) : a, r \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_p\}.
$$

Is still secure DDH with multiple instances? That is, is hard to distinguish two following distributions?
$$ 
\{ (g, g^a, g^{b_i}, g^{ab_i}) : a, b_i \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_p\} \text{ and } \{ (g, g^a,g^{b_i}, g^r) : a, r_i \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_p\}.
$$
We also suppose that the cardinality of the set, $|\{b_i\}|$, is much smaller than $p$ to avoid easy cases.

Comment: Is it naturally true due to the self-reducibility of DDH?

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, you should clarify it.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau No. Not homework. just curious things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be solved via a standard hybrid argument. I won't give you all the details. However, note that given a single tuple $(g,h_1,h_2,h_3)$ you can generate a tuple of the form $(g,g^a,g^{b_i},g^{ab_i})$ by choosing $b_i$ and forming $(g,h_1,g^{b_i},h_1^{b_i})$ and you can generate a tuple of the form $(g,g^a,g^{b_i},g^r)$ by choosing $b_i$ and forming $(g,h_1,g^{b_i},g^r)$. This suffices for building hybrid distributions as needed for a hybrid argument.

Comment: Thank you for your hopeful comments!